# Loading an text over an image without text moving when screen size changes

Tags: css

Every time my screen size changes the text moves on the page, i want the text to load in one set place on the image, no matter what the sceen size is. My CSS looks like this.

```
form {position:absolute; left: 1233px;display:inline-block;z-index:80; top: 215;}
```

This loads it in the correct place on the screen.

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML?

Comment: just use `%`instead of fixed units.

Comment: use css media queries and `%` instead of fixed units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it must be `top: 215px`, otherwise it's not working.

When dealing with responsive content you must use `%` instead of fixed `px` size.

```
form {    
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px; // There must be fixed number: element width / 2
    display: inline-block;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 80;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but what about the top now as the i cannot lower the text on the image using top: 215